# FORWARD_NULL Vs UNINIT Coverity errors in C

Tags: c, coverity

when a pointer is initialized to NULL, getting "FORWARD_NULL" coverity errors and when the NULL initialization is removed, it throws UNINIT coverity errors. The code is as below.

I am very new to coverity. If its a very basic question also, please help.

I am

1) declaring a pointer,

2) Initializing it to NULL and

3) deferring it without assigning anything to it.

This deference is an argument in a function call inside which, it will be filled in. Getting FORWARD_NULL errors for the same. Started with Coverity works, from yesterday only.

```
int fn1()
{
    strct1 *pvarA = NULL;
    if (fn2(&pvarA) != 0) // derefering NULL pointer error.
    {
        return 1;
    }
    ...
    /* some code */
}

int fn2(strct1 **pvarA)
{
    ...
    /* some code */
    *pvarA = varA;
    /* some code */
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks,
Preethi

Comment: How exactly does this code makes sense to you? As for why it complains if you drop the NULL, we cannot say without a [mcve]. It could also be a tool bug, but none can tell with what's given here.

Comment: FORWARD_NULL implies that you're dereferencing the `NULL`, but that's not what your code shows.

Comment: Your code doesn't match your question. Did you mean `*a = **ar`?

Comment: Nope. It is matching. @Jabberwocky I wanted to do `a = *ar`. But in the line `int *a = NULL`, getting coverity error as mentioned in the comments `/* */`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This helps easily:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

strct1
{
    int a;
    int b;
    char c;
};

int fn1()
{
    strct1 *pvarA = NULL;
    strct1 varA;

    MEMSET(&varA, 0, sizeof (strct1));
    pvarA = &varA;
    if (fn2(&pvarA) != 0) // derefering NULL pointer error.
    {
        return 1;
    }
    /* some code */
}

int fn2(strct1 **pvarA)
{
    /* some code */
    *pvarA = varA;
    /* some code */
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In such code:

```
int fn1(int **ar)
{
    int *a;
    a = *ar;
}
```

The variable `a` is not initialized (thus `UNINIT`) and the variable `ar` is dereferenced without checking for null (thus `FORWARD_NULL`).

Probably this code will work:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int fn1(int **ar)
{
   int *a = NULL;
   if (ar == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Omg! you passed NULL as first argument to fn1 function. What to do now? Break the program flow for sure - return or abort() or exit() !");
        abort();
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    a = *ar;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Trying it out. Once it is going to work, will update this as answer.

Comment: I did this:
`int fn1(int **ar)
{
int *a = NULL; /* throws forward null, when NULL is removed, coverity throws unint errors. */
if (ar == NULL) { return 1;}
a = *ar;
}`
My coverity error still exists. @kamil